# Apple Mac / Pop!OS keyboard issues

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, macintosh, parallels

`Apple Mac Pro (early 2009)
Full size slim aluminium keyboard with extended layout. UK edition
.4.1 -> 5.1 firmware upgraded
macOS 10.13.4 High Sierra
Parallels 13 for Apple Mac
Parallels Tools
Pop!OS 17.10 (Ubuntu)`

I have been redirected to this board because despite being based on Ubuntu, it seems that Pop!OS is not supported on askubuntu.com. Apologies for any undue angst this may have caused!

Hello, I have just installed Pop!OS, which I believe is Ubuntu under the hood, but despite selecting a Macintosh keyboard as part of the installation process, I am experiencing the usual keyboard quirks, <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd> swapped, no access to <kbd>~</kbd> (tilde) or <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick), that sort of thing. Can anyone who has had direct experience of this problem advise me what I can do to fix it.

I've already waded through lots of documentation, and while I freely accept I may have missed something, everything I've seen has been irrelevant, incomplete or outdated, or a combination of some/all three!

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: dumb question: did you select **English (Macintosh)** or **English (UK,Macintosh)**?

Comment: I cannot remember for sure, but given the choice, I would have thought that I would have chosen English (UK, Macintosh) since I am aware that there are several nations that speak English. I have tried going into the GUI settings and selecting UK for the language and regional settings, but when I checked the keyboard settings that was more concerned with application shortcut settings. Is there any command line tool that can help? Silly question, this is Linux after all, of course there is. I should ask, what is it?